# Remove controller name from URL with Attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to remove controller name from URL for specific Controller.

My Controller name is **Product**

I found some link to do this

[Routing with and without controller name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836401/routing-with-and-without-controller-name-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

[MVC Routing without controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047155/mvc-routing-without-controller-in-the-url)

But all the above links done in route config file. and those are affecting other controller too. I want to do it using Attribute Routing.

Can it is possible? As I want to do this for only Product controller.

I have tried to do it on action like this

```
[Route("Sample/{Name}")]
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel's answer is right, however, it can be a bit misleading since you're asking for MVC and that answer is for Web API.

In any case, what you want is to put the annotation over the **class definition** instead of an action method. MVC example would be like:

```
[RoutePrefix("SomethingOtherThanProduct")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
           ...
           return View();
      }
}
```

I'm also dropping this as an answer since you may find the following article helpful: [[Attribute] Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5 / WebAPI 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774807/Attribute-Routing-in-ASP-NET-MVC-WebAPI)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the RoutePrefix attribute on the whole controller class, as well as using the Route attribute on the action.

```
[RoutePrefix("notproducts")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get() { ... }
}
```